# SSD gives DMA boot errors while smartctrl shows no error

Tags: centos, ssd

I installed an OCZ-ARC100 in a Dell Poweredge T105. The latter shows BDMA errors when I boot the system (CentOS 7) with it:

```
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: ATA-8: OCZ-ARC100, 1.01, max UDMA/133
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: 234441648 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      OCZ-ARC100       1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/111 GiB)
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel:  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: BMDMA stat 0x5
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: cmd c8/00:08:00:4b:f9/00:00:00:00:00/ed tag 0 dma 4096 in
                                                        res 51/04:08:00:4b:f9/00:00:00:00:00/ed Emask 0x1 (device error)
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: error: { ABRT }
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
jun 25 15:40:21 myhost kernel: ata4: EH complete
...
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4: EH complete
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: BMDMA stat 0x5
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: cmd c8/00:08:d0:47:f9/00:00:00:00:00/ed tag 0 dma 4096 in
                                                        res 51/04:08:d0:47:f9/00:00:00:00:00/ed Emask 0x1 (device error)
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: error: { ABRT }
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4: EH complete
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: limiting speed to UDMA/100:PIO4
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: BMDMA stat 0x5
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: failed command: READ DMA
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: cmd c8/00:08:f8:47:f9/00:00:00:00:00/ed tag 0 dma 4096 in
                                                        res 51/04:08:f8:47:f9/00:00:00:00:00/ed Emask 0x1 (device error)
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: error: { ABRT }
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4: hard resetting link
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4: nv: skipping hardreset on occupied port
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4.00: configured for UDMA/100
jun 25 15:40:22 myhost kernel: ata4: EH complete
```

I plugged the OCZ on a SATA-to-USB2 adapter and ran smartctrl:

```
smartctl 6.4 2015-06-04 r4109 [x86_64-linux-4.4.6-gentoo-nvidia] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-15, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     OCZ-ARC100
Serial Number:    A22L0061518000567
LU WWN Device Id: 5 e83a97 100061d69
Firmware Version: 1.01
User Capacity:    120.034.123.776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jun 25 15:28:55 2017 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x1d) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Abort Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x00) Error logging NOT supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   0) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 18
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       252
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       84
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       39711824
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       10
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
208 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       5
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
224 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       100
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       92
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       221
249 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3316691

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

Warning! SMART Self-Test Log Structure error: invalid SMART checksum.
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

Clearly there's no sign of error here. I didn't pay too much attention though to the BMDMA errors and initially thought the drive was going to die but now I'm doubting this is the proper diagnostics. I was also mislead by the fact that replacing the drive with a brand new one (Western Digital Blue 500GB) worked like a charm without error. However the difference is the OCZ is actually blazingly fast in comparison.

How should I interpret these errors above (obviously DMA errors) and how can I fix this issue? Flash the OCZ firmware, for instance? Use specific kernel arguments?

By the way the BIOS mandates the bus option `ATA` for SATA disks. It is not possible to change, for instance, to AHCI. I assume it is due to either the CD/DVD drive that is connected to the SATA bus or the presence of a Fusion MPT hardware Raid adapter. Anyway I don't have a choice (literally) here but it doesn't seem to matter at least with the WD drive.

---

**EDIT:** I ran a drive self test from the server itself and here are the results:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 18
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       253
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       85
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       39711824
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       10
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
208 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       5
210 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
224 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       100
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       92
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       222
249 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3316768

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       253         -
```

Also, and as [meuh hints](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373276/ssd-gives-dma-boot-errors-while-smartctrl-shows-no-error?noredirect=1#comment663854_373276) smartctl tests the internals of the drive, I think I can safely assume the drive is not faulty. I'll investigate some more...

Comment: In my personal experience, YMMV, SMART tools have not worked well when using USB. Plug the drive onto a SATA port on another computer, then inspect SMART test data. Did you see `invalid SMART checksum.` ? Does not look too reliable to me!

Comment: @thecarpy Oops! Didn't pay enough attention to that either. I'll run `smartctrl -t` as suggested. As for another machine, well, I have one but it's really not that straightforward to put the drive in it.

Comment: smart is for the "inside" of the disk, whereas dma errors are more indicative of problems on the bus from the drive to the computer, eg the cable, socket, or perhaps inadequate power or electrical noise interference. You might try forcing the bus link speed down from 1.5G to see (sorry, I don't remember how to do that). It can also be a disk firmware bug of course, so if you know of new firmware you should indeed try it.

Comment: Thanks @meuh . Seems to rule out a drive fault, which is always reassuring. I'm not sure about the cables though — maybe I put too much trust in Dell products but given that another drive doesn't exhibit those errors... I'll try switching speed as you suggested.

Comment: There's a catch 22 here: I must set the SATA controller to AHCI to flash the firmware onto the unit... which is impossible on the server itself. Guess I'll have to find another way and I bet this is the reason for these errors. Let's see...